# Separate CSS file for each angular2 component affects performance of page?

Tags: html, performance, css, angular, http-request

All the guides about Angular2 propose to have a separate file for css styling for each component. As I get is so far, for each custom directive there is the need to make requests to the server to get the html and css for that directive (component). If this is the case, what is the performance impact for the page when multiple requests are made for multiple directives? Is there any other recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

That's only true during development. A build step (currently work in progress) will inline resources and generate code for declarative bindings. In the end there will be only a minimum number of requests.

Some related issues:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8717
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8550
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8759
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8097
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6612#issuecomment-175894674
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8400